# ModuleConfig and PluginConfig in Struts 2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts, struts-1

I'm working on Struts 2 migration. My Struts 1 application is using `ModuleConfig` and `PlugInConfig` classes. How to use these classes in Struts 2?

Comment: You don't, they don't exist. What were you using them for? Personally, I view moving from S1 to S2 as a rewrite, not a migration: everything in the web layer needs to be rewritten, nothing in the business layer does.

Comment: Keep in mind that Struts2 is a completely different framework from Struts1, it's not merely a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModuleConfig` and `PlugInConfig` are Struts1 classes. Struts2 framework is different in [architecture](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/big-picture) and uses it's own classes used to parse and build the configuration. So, if your application used those classes and you unable to remove them at the moment you should consider the option to run both frameworks together. Also, if you decide to remove them after rewriting the configuration, but want to reuse actions and forms in Struts2 consider [struts2-struts1-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/struts-1) and [struts1-solutions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14240#content/view/14240). This allows to use existing actions and forms in the Struts2 framework, but this is more complicated in Struts2 rather than writing a Struts2 only web application from scratch.

Comment: Ok...thanks for your response. But my requirement is to develop the entire struts1 application in struts2.                                I have one more question:                                          What is Struts 2 equivalent of <plug-in>?

Comment: @user2337055 There's not equivalent, Struts2 uses `bean` element in the configuration for their extensions and plug-ins, that was provided via the `struts-plugin.xml`.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. My configuration is like this in struts1 struts-config.xml file 
<plug-in className="com.web.action.TabPlugIn">
   <set-property property="config" value="/WEB-INF/tab/" />
   <set-property property="class" value="com.web.action.XmlTabSystem" />
    <set-property property="excludes" value="/k1/stylesheet" />
  </plug-in>
In my struts-plugin.xml
<struts>
    <bean class="com.web.action.TabPlugIn " static="true" optional="true"/>
</struts>
Could you please tell me how do I define properties to the bean in struts-plugin xml file. Thanks

Comment: Easy with DI (dependency injection) if you don't want to use Struts2 DI then you could choose between known containers like Spring, CDI, Guice, etc.